# Colour picker in angular2

Tags: angular, color-picker, angular2-directives

I want to use a color picker in angular2. I tried using npm [angular2-color-picker](https://github.com/Alberplz/angular2-color-picker) library. But i could see only a blank screen after including the directive. (No error found in console). Please help me by knowing where i am going wrong or let me know whether there is any other angular2 library available for color picking.Thanks in advance.

My HTML includes:

```
<div>
<label>Primary</label>
<input [(colorPicker)]="color" [style.background]="color" [value]="color"/>
</div>
```

My TS: (AppComponent page routes to DesignPage)

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {ColorPickerDirective} from 'angular2-color-picker/app/color-picker/color-picker.directive';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-design',
    templateUrl: 'wwwWeb/build/component/design/design.html',
    directives: [ColorPickerDirective]
})
export class DesignPage implements OnInit {
 private color: string = "#127bdc";
}
```

My Boot.ts

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {ColorPickerService} from './color-picker/color-picker.service'

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ColorPickerService]);
```

My Tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "../node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the library this way:

```
System.config({
  map: {
    'angular2-color-picker': 'node_modules/angular2-color-picker'
  },
  packages: {
    (...)
    'angular2-color-picker': {
      format: 'register',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: i am using commonjs as modules

Comment: The library is compiled as SystemJS modules. If you want to use it with comonjs, you need to recompile it. Could you add in your question the configuration of the TypeScript compiler you use? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. i have edited my question

Comment: Sorry but i didnt understand your solution.
Where do i need to configure this?
I am trying to add this component to ionic 2.
Thanks