# Angular2 ionic 2 Color picker

Tags: jquery, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

i want to use a color picker in ionic 2 . I using angular2-color-picker From [here](https://github.com/Alberplz/angular2-color-picker#options). as per the doc folder added pages/color-picker. please help me some thing missing or what can i do?

its Get error

> No provider for ColorPickerService!

My.html

```
<ion-input [(colorPicker)]="color" [style.background]="color" [value]="color"></ion-input>
```

my.ts

```js
import {ColorPickerDirective} from '../color-picker/color-picker.directive'
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/trans-generation/trans-generation.html',
  directives: [ColorPickerDirective]
})
export class TransGeneration {
  private color: string = "#127bdc";
}
```

app.ts

```js
import {TransGeneration} from './pages/trans-generation/trans-generation';
import {ColorPickerService} from './pages/color-picker/color-picker.service'

ionicBootstrap(MyApp,TransGeneration, [ColorPickerService])
```

Comment: Are you able to get the non-rounded color picker?

Comment: no..error message   "No provider for ColorPickerService!"

Comment: Did you already give a look at this [other SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36772233/colour-picker-in-angular2) ?

Answer (score 1):

Import ColorPickerModule line in your app.module.ts file it should work fine.

```
import {ColorPickerModule} from 'angular2-color-picker';

@NgModule({
    ...
    imports: [ColorPickerModule]
})
```